# How to match 2nd instance in regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

`get_by_my_column`

If I only want to match the `get_by` portion of the above string, how can I do this?  I keep reading on this [regex cheatsheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) that I should use `\n` but I can't figure out how to implement it properly...

I've tried variations of the following...

```
/((_){2})/
/(_+){2}/
```

Comment: Please clarify why `get_by`, and not `get` or `bet_by_my`? What logic do you follow selecting only that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/(\w+?_\w+?)_\w+/` (use non greedy quantifiers, your substring should be in capture group 1)

or just `/\w+?_\w+?/` <---(edit: won't work, you do need that second underscore as regex structure to force the non greedy \w up to it :])

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use a regex for this? You could use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and just grab the first two elements of the resulting array.

Comment: `Do you need to use a regex for this?` --- curious, what if I ask `Do you need to use explode() for this?`? Why explode is better than regexp in this particular question?

Comment: @zerkms - PHP is not my forte, just bringing something different to the table!

Comment: @Webnet - one line of code is one line of code, the only real difference is how it reads

Comment: +1 explode() would be faster, as long as your only requirement is to split by `_` and get the first two results.

Comment: @Ethan: speed makes no sense for operations that works in microseconds.

Comment: @ninesided: for 10 char string and one call there is literally no difference how it reads and how it works

Comment: @zerkms - I disagree - perhaps it's the fact that I don't use regex that often, but I can never look at one and immediately know what it's doing, I rely on comments or I have to "parse" it in my brain first. Explode is simple, it's immediately clear what is happening.

Comment: @zerkms - also "speed makes no sense for operations that works in microseconds - wow, sweeping statement of the day! Tell that to the guys doing algorithmic trading or processing massive datasets! :) In the context of PHP however, I'm inclined to agree.

Comment: @ninesided: `I can never look at one and immediately know what it's doing` -- are you sure? `^\w+_\w+` is terribly simple regular expression. While `explode()` would introduce several lines implementation with several extra checks (to check if there are at least 2 underscores). I vote for one-liner in this case. `Explode is simple, it's immediately clear what is happening.` --- could you please bother writing a complete sample so we could compare them? I cannot compare things I don't see.

Comment: "Tell that to the guys doing algorithmic trading or processing massive datasets" --- doubtfully the person who asks such question has anything even near to one request per second ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try

`preg_match('/(^[a-z]+[_][a-z]+)/', $string, $results);`

This matches a string that starts with a group of letters followed by an underscore followed by another set of letters.

**Edit:** (lowercase letters)

Comment: `[_]` is equal to just `_`. Also you don't need parentheses - the whole match falls into 0th element of results anyway

Answer (score 0):

try `/^get_by`. 
`^` for the condition that g must be the starting character.